# Multiple image inputs within one form?

Tags: php, forms, image-uploading, multiple-file-upload

Most problems I see are with ONE image input.  But what if you have 2 or 3 or more?

My script for one image input worked but I am trying to have one single-image input and one multiple image input in my form.  I'm testing out having 2 single-image inputs on my form but not working.

Here is the HTML for one single-image input (assume it is inside a < form > tag):

```
  <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000"/>
  <input type="file" name="schoollogo"/><br/>
```

The PHP:

```
  $target = "images/logo/";
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['schoollogo']['name']);

  $schoollogo = $_FILES['schoollogo']['name'];

  //Writes the information to the database

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO Colleges (schoollogo) VALUES ('$schoollogo')") or die(mysql_error()) ;

  //Writes the logo to the server
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['schoollogo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      //Tells you if its all ok
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
  } else {
      //Gives and error if its not
      echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
  }
```

For the second single-image input, I just added a second input code...

```
 <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000"/>
 <input type="file" name="otherimage"/><br/>
```

And then added the variable to the PHP:

```
  $targetotherimage = "images/otherimage/";
  $targetotherimage = $targetotherimage . basename( $_FILES['otherimage']['name']);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO Colleges (schoollogo,otherimage) VALUES ('$schoollogo','$otherimage')") or die(mysql_error()) ;

  //Writes the logo to the server
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['schoollogo']['tmp_name'], $target)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['otherimage']['tmp_name'], $targetotherimage)) {
```

but when adding that code into the PHP, the code does not work.  No error messages or anything.  The page is blank.

By the way, [here is my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682844/single-image-input-and-multiple-image-input-on-form) where I am attempting to add a multiple-image upload input into my form with an already-working single-image upload input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP? - Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong closing of if condition.

```
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['schoollogo']['tmp_name'], $target)) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['otherimage']['tmp_name'], $targetotherimage)) {
                                                                  ^^^^// In your code if condition close here
```

It is used as

```
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['schoollogo']['tmp_name'], $target) 

&& (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['otherimage']['tmp_name'],  $targetotherimage)))//if condition close here 
{
// rest of code

}
```

Comment: I have, but nothing changed. No errors.  Still blank page after I made the changes you suggested.

Comment: use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check error on page

Comment: Works, thanks! Now that I have 2 single-file upload inputs working, I gotta figure out how to convert the second input into a multiple-file upload input.

Comment: The other answer was good but your answer helped solve my code directly as is without changing the code as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you, replace your form with this

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
      <input type="file" name="file['schoollogo']" >
      <input type="file" name="file['otherimage']" >
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You will get your files in this format:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    ['schoollogo'] => 1465386599_Location_Outline-36.png
                    ['otherimage'] => STONE_Website_v7E.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    ['schoollogo'] => image/png
                    ['otherimage'] => image/jpeg
                )
        ) 
)
```

And in upload.php file

```
<?php 
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) 
{
     $schoollogo=$_FILES['file']['name']['schoollogo'];
     $target = "images/logo/".basename($schoollogo);;

     $otherimage = $_FILES['file']['name']['otherimage'];
     $targetotherimage = "images/otherimage/".basename($otherimage);

      $tmp_name_school = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['schoollogo'];
      $tmp_name_other = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['otherimage'];

      if ($tmp_name_school != "" && $tmp_name_other !== "")
      {
        //Upload the file 
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_school,$target) && move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_other, $targetotherimage)) 
        {
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO Colleges (schoollogo,otherimage) VALUES ('$schoollogo','$otherimage')") or die(mysql_error()) ;
          echo'Done!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not Moved";
        }
      }
}   
?>
```